# Cross domain cookie for same Drupal installation

Tags: cookies

The English translation of my Drupal installation runs on MYSITE.com and my German translation runs on MYSITE.de. Of course, I want my users to be able to switch languages without having to log in again.

I read that there is no way to set cross domain cookies for domain1.com and domain2.com if they point to different websites, only for *subdomains* 1.domain.com and 2.domain.com. Is there any way to set a cross domain cookie in my case, where both domains point to the same installation?

Comment: This other post is relevant: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51261/how-to-use-different-domains-for-multilingual-sites-and-keep-users-logged-in

Comment: No there's no way to do this - MYSITE.com and MYSITE.de are different domains, the fact that they're served from the same Drupal installation is irrelevant

Comment: Thank you, all the information I need is in the thread linked. I apologize for the duplicate.